# use cache in GCM chat App- android

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I develop a simple android chat using GCM and PHP, if there is an internet connection everything is work fine and the message sent and received from other side fine, the problem when there is no internet connection i want the data to be cached until the device connect to internet and then the message send automatically via GCM. any idea for this ???

Thanks in advance

Comment: For one suggestion you could store this data in a sqlite database until you need to send it to your server.

Comment: thank you, but how to automate the process, i mean when a internet availbe the message send automatically like whatsapp.

Comment: You have to roll out your own way of achieving this, as far as I can tell there is no automated way. You have to store your data locally somehow then check for internet connectivity then carry out the sync process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define a timeout interval, check for internet connectivity using a thread or intent service after the expiration of the timeout interval. if internet conectivity is not available, cache it to sqlite database, when internet connectivity is available, push them and flush the local sqlite cache.